# Remove Substring in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, I need to find a substring between `&J=` and `Key` using regex and remove it from my url which could contain several substrings.

Here is my url:

```
SID=18608202881669&Act=432&Mode=1&CLk=T&Key58=6003&dotnetdll=TopCoConfigurator.dll&dotnetfunc=CasingSizeSummary&SID=18608202881669&F=&J=CasingSize/CasingSizeSummary.asp&Key58=6003&ccs_casingsizeid=6003
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not "can someone please write a regex for me".

Comment: Why must it use a regular expression?

Comment: use javascript `replace()`  function for strings

Comment: You should try this to find all substrings b/w &J= and Key / (?<=\S)&(.*?)(?=Key) /g

Answer (score 0):

You can [learn Regular Expression here](http://www.regexr.com/) and code for your problem is: 
Here you go:

```
    SID="18608202881669&Act=432&Mode=1&CLk=T&Key58=6003&dotnetdll=TopCoConfigurator.dll&dotnetfunc=CasingSizeSummary&SID=18608202881669&F=&J=CasingSize/CasingSizeSummary.asp&Key58=6003&ccs_casingsizeid=6003";

var re = /&J=(.*?)&Key/;
SID = SID.replace(re, '');
alert(SID);
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pttwd6z2/)